# SoundPool - What position in a sound file

Tags: android, soundpool

I have loaded sounds using Soundpool in Android.

I have used the `play` function to play the sound.

How do I know how long a file is and where I am currently in that file as it is playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sound File Duration**

[`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) is probably your best bet, here:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(ctxt, R.raw.mysound);
int duration = player.getDuration();
player.release();    //(If not using this player later on)
```

**Current Playback Position**

`SoundPool` does not support this functionality. Your three main options:

1. Use `MediaPlayer` for playback. `MediaPlayer` supplies a `getCurrentPosition()` method.
2. Use [`AudioTrack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) -- manually sending uncompressed audio to the stream on a byte-by-byte basis. `AudioTrack` has some basic functionality for determining playback position (usually accurate to within a few tens of milliseconds, on most devices), and besides that you can know exactly how much audio's been added to the playback buffer.
3. Stick with `SoundPool`, but time the playback yourself. That is, take a time hack ([`SystemClock.UptimeMillis()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis())) or set a [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer), and estimate your playback position by assuming that playback began as soon as `play()` returned. This approach is rife with problems and inaccuracies, but has the benefit of not involving `AudioTrack's` complexity.